# What is the UI guide to show a list of choices (UItableView presumably) and an text editor together in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

So I have this use-case where I have to show a list of items and user chooses one them. Right now, the list of items is shown as a full screen table view (with each option as a row). However, now I have to show an edit box so that the user can input an item in case he does not like any from the list.

I tried checking for a UI guidance for the same but could not find. any pointers ??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming per se. It is better suited for http://ux.stackexchange.com/ IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the UITableView and to add new items you can put a button in the header of tableview "Add", upon tapping that you display UIAlertController with TextEdit subview and necessary buttons.

Comment: I have followed something like this on my final code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you do is right. You can found some example from Contact app in your iPhone.

when adding new contact with phone number you can choose a label from list and you can add customer label as well.